# Ordenar resultados por uma coluna do relacionamento no Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Atualmente possuo alguns métodos que usados em conjunto permitem que eu faça requests para minha aplicação controlando os "withs", "orders" e tal via querystring.
Posso fazer, por exemplo:

`GET /users?sort=name&sex=female`

Neste caso a aplicação irá retornar uma lista de usuários de sexo feminino e ordenados por nome.

O que eu preciso fazer agora é ordenar os resultados pela coluna de uma tabela relacionada. Como o Laravel faz duas queries quando usamos o médoto `with()`, a ordenação só é possível por uma coluna da tabela do model que está fazendo a busca.
Existe alguma forma de fazer o que eu quero, além de montar a consulta e os joins na mão pelo builder?
Também vi que dá para fazer com o `sortBy` da Collection, porém este mesmo código que tenho lida com paginação e, neste caso, fazendo pela collection iria ordenar apenas os dados que já vieram do banco.

Comment: Foi editado e colocado esse item *Modo com with, join e orderBy* é a única forma de se fazer o que você ta querendo, com with, join e orderBy da relação, funcionou perfeitamente agora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exemplo:**

***SQL de criação das tabelas***

```
CREATE TABLE `creditos` (
  `creditoid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`creditoid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `creditoid_UNIQUE` (`creditoid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `noticias` (
  `noticiaid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creditoid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subtitulo` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `texto` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `hora` time NOT NULL,
  `fotocapa` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`noticiaid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `noticiaid_UNIQUE` (`noticiaid`),
  KEY `pk2creditoId_idx` (`creditoid`),
  CONSTRAINT `pk2creditoId` FOREIGN KEY (`creditoid`) REFERENCES `creditos` (`creditoid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

---

***Models dessas duas tabelas (Eloquent)***

*Credito*

```
<?php
class Credito extends Eloquent {
    public $table      = 'creditos'; 
    public $primaryKey = 'creditoid';
    public $timestamps = true;
    public function noticia()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Noticia', 'creditoid');
    }           
    public function getDates()
    {
        return array('created_at','updated_at');
    }
}
```

*Noticia*

```
<?php
class Noticia extends Eloquent {
    public $table      = 'noticias'; 
    public $primaryKey = 'noticiaid';
    public $timestamps = true;  
    public function credito()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Credito', 'creditoid');
    }    
    public function getDates()
    {
        return array('created_at','updated_at');
    }
}
```

***Pesquisa pelo relacionamento entre essas tabelas fazendo um [like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) na descricao do Credito e `order by` no `Creditos.Descricao` (tabela do relacionamento)***

**[Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)**

*Modo com with*

```
Noticia::with(array('Credito' => function($query){
        $query->where('creditos.descricao', 'like', '%a%');
        $query->orderBy('creditos.descricao');
    }))->get();
```

*Modo com join*

```
Noticia::join('creditos', 'creditos.creditoid', '=', 'noticias.creditoid')
         ->where('creditos.descricao', 'like', '%a%')
         ->orderBy('creditos.descricao', 'desc')
         ->get();
```

*Modo com with, join e orderBy*

```
Noticia::with('Credito')
        ->join('creditos', 'creditos.creditoid','=', 'noticias.creditoid')
        ->orderBy('creditos.descricao')
        ->get();
```

**[Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)**

```
DB::table("noticias")
        ->join('creditos', 'creditos.creditoid', '=', 'noticias.creditoid')
        ->where('creditos.descricao', 'like', '%a%')
        ->orderBy('creditos.descricao', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

<sup>**Obs**: Foi colocado `where` e `orderBy` juntos de propósito, para mostrar as diversas possibilidades, sendo que pode usar só o que precisa que no caso seria `orderBy`. Outra coisa se puder dar uma opinião utilize com o modo `join` é bem mais *transparente*</sup>

*Referências:*

- [SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)
- [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)
- [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)
- [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)
- [Selects](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!
Mas acho que ainda não chegamos lá. Veja só:

**Modo com with**
Desta forma continua produzindo duas queries, então não funciona. Ele ordena os resultados da segunda pela ordem especificada, o que não ordena os resultados da tabela onde eu estou procurando os dados originalmente.

**Modo com join e QueryBuilder**
O problema desta abordagem é que ele não faz os agrupamentos do resultado de acordo com o relacionamento... A ordenação funciona, mas perco o relacionamento (embora eu possa tratar isso depois, então é uma opção ainda, mesmo que envolva um passo a mais).

Comment: O modo com with, join e orderBy, apesar de produzir duas queries, realmente faz o esperado e mantém o relacionamento.

Answer (score 1):

Eu criei um package [laraerp/ordination](https://packagist.org/packages/laraerp/ordination) para utilizar nos meus projetos. Ele possui uma trait que ao adicioná-la no seu model,o método orderBy é reescrito. Com ele você poderá enviar uma requisição do tipo:

```
GET /cliente?by=pessoa.razao_apelido&order=desc
```

No exemplo a tabela Cliente possui um belongsTo Pessoa.

Segue [link do tutorial](http://www.jansenfelipe.com.br/laravel-como-criar-uma-lista-de-registros-ordenacao/).

Comment: Jansen, bem legal o seu package. Só gostaria de enfatizar que ele não irá funcionar no Laravel 4 (que é a versão utilizada nessa pergunta)

Comment: Putz, me desculpe.. nem tinha reparado que era para o Laravel4.. Mas me deu uma idéia: permitir o suporte para o L4! :)

Comment: Não sei se vale a pena não =) Eu ficaria somente com o Laravel 5 mesmo. É legal adicionar alguns testes também.